# How do I select a region in pie chart (Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to select a region in pie chart and pop an alert saying `You selected Jane/Joe etc.` How do I perform an `onclick` function upon clicking on a certain area inside a pie chart?

Here is the link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfXE5/)

Comment: Your code needs to go in the question. Your question cannot depend on a link to a 3rd party site to be answerable. Once you've produced a [short self-contained example](http://sscce.org) in your question, you may *supplement( your question with a link to a site like JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modified] To keep the code in the Highchart definition, change the `type: 'pie'` series to include events sections like this:

```
          {
          type: 'pie',
          data: [
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
          ],
          center: [30, 0],
          size: 100,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          showInLegend: true,
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: false,
          },
          point :{
            events:{
              click : function(){
                alert(this.name);
              }
            }
          },
```

PS. Had to extend your load SetInterval(...) value from 1000 to 10000 so the events could be captured reliably.

Comment: Well cant I make it more generic? I mean is there something like I write this events function only once for every data series.

Comment: I've tried this, but it only clicks only sometimes. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfXE5/37/)

Comment: I mean the pie chart does not clicks every time(1 in 20 times). Can you pleae tell why?

Comment: Try clicking on the light blue region. Out of 10 times you click, it will alert only once. Same for dark blue region. And it doesnt click at all for green region

Comment: You probably didn't change the SetInterval on your onload. I suspect the event queue can't handle so many updates. If you change the SetInterval to something like 10000, it works every time.

Comment: I tried your code as well. Your code has the same problem, ie clicks once in 10 times.

Comment: Works like a charm. Changed the time interval and its awesome. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

check this out. it alerts 'fill' of the region you clicked on http://jsfiddle.net/bfXE5/19/
All you need is to add this code to your jQuery

```
   $('path').click(function(){
         alert ($(this).attr('fill'));
     });
```

The onle problem I see is that there is not many things to alert. And you might want to add some more description to your pie, like names for every piece, or something else, that will make sense to alert

Comment: How do I alert the name of the selected region?

Comment: *such as `Jane, Joe / John`

Comment: I've tried this, but it only clicks only sometimes. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfXE5/37/)
I mean the pie chart does not clicks every time(1 in 20 times). Can you pleae tell why?

Comment: Try clicking on the light blue region. Out of 10 times you click, it will alert only once. Same for dark blue region. And it doesnt click at all for green region

Comment: if you want to alert the name of pie selected - you need to give it a name. currently in your code there is no names for them

Comment: And your code pops alert even when clicked on line points. I want to  alert names only when the pie chart is clicked

Comment: check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/bfXE5/39/ I changed the time interval and it works just fine. it looks to me that your function just getting too busy to alert something.